# How to retrieve all the Data from Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1BTa.jpg)

The Picture above is my Firestore.

I'm trying to retrieve all the data from the Collection UserData.

This is the Code I used. I'm not getting any Red lines or error in Console but its not showing the data of the Collection UserData. Please Help

```
  Container(
      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserData')
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Something went wrong');
            }

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Text("Loading");
            }

            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DocumentSnapshot book = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                return ListTile(
                  leading: Text(book['title']),
                  title: Text(book['Date']),
                  subtitle: Text(book['Time']),
                );
              },
            );
          }
      )
  ),
```

Comment: Use `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserData/id/bookings').snapshots()` where id is the id of the userData you want e.g '5arB1rZr1b...'

Comment: It's still not showing sir.

Comment: What id are you using?

Comment: I'll explain, this application is about booking and the code i posted is the admin side, It supposes to get all the data that the users input all different users booking will be shown in a ListView please mr. Peter I really need your help

Comment: Okay, if you want to get all users bookings, you use a `collectionGroup`. For example: `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('bookings')`. This should return all bookings for all users.

Comment: Sir Peter Thank you so much for your Help I've search everywhere hours days but yours work thank you so much.